# Should I delete my duplicate answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

I was looking for solutions for measuring string height of a HTML5 canvas element. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134586/how-can-you-find-the-height-of-text-on-an-html-canvas/13730758#13730758)
solution but that doesn't satisfied my needs. Later, when I came up with my own solution, I come back and made my own answer. But then while looking at other answers more attentively I found that one answer uses the same approach as mine.

Should I delete my answer or not? Should I add answers with the same approach but different content?

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to add another answer if it doesn't add anything new to what has been said before. If the difference is minor but (in your opinion) important, edit your findings into the earlier answer.